# GluonCV object detection fine-tuning - Select which layers are modified (freeze the rest)

Tags: object-detection, mxnet, mxnet-gluon

I have a question about the procedure for fine-tuning a pre-trained object detection model with GluonCV, described in [this tutorial](https://cv.gluon.ai/build/examples_detection/finetune_detection.html).

As far as I understand, the described procedure modifies all the weight values in the model.
I wanted to only fine-tune the fully connected layer at the end of the network, and freeze the rest of the weights.

I assume that I should specify which parameters I want to modify when creating the Trainer:

```
trainer = gluon.Trainer(net.collect_params(), 'sgd', {'learning_rate': 0.001, 'wd': 0.0005, 'momentum': 0.9})
```

so, instead of net.collect_params(), I should list the parameters I’m interested in training, and run the rest of the process normally.
However, I don’t know how to isolate these parameters precisely…I tried printing:

```
params = net.collect_params()
```

but, out of this list, I don’t know which ones correspond to the final FC layers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a pretrained Gluon model for a classification task:

```py
>>> import mxnet as mx
>>> net = mx.gluon.nn.HybridSequential()
>>> net.add(mx.gluon.nn.Conv2D(channels=6, kernel_size=5, padding=2, activation='sigmoid'))
>>> net.add(mx.gluon.nn.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
>>> net.add(mx.gluon.nn.Flatten())
>>> net.add(mx.gluon.nn.Dense(units=10))
>>> net.collect_params()
hybridsequential0_ (
  Parameter conv0_weight (shape=(6, 0, 5, 5), dtype=<class 'numpy.float32'>)
  Parameter conv0_bias (shape=(6,), dtype=<class 'numpy.float32'>)
  Parameter dense0_weight (shape=(1, 0), dtype=float32)
  Parameter dense0_bias (shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
)
```

To fine-tune this convolutional network, we want to freeze all the blocks except `Dense`.

First, recall that `collect_params` method accepts a regexp string to choose specific block parameters by their names (or prefixes; `prefix` parameter of `Conv2D`, `Dense`, or any other Gluon (hybrid) block). By default, the prefixes are class names, i.e. if a block is `Conv2D` then the prefix is `conv0_` or `conv1_` etc. Moreover, `collect_params` returns an instance of `mxnet.gluon.parameter.ParameterDict`, which has `setattr` method.

Solution:

```py
>>> conv_params = net.collect_params('(?!dense).*')
>>> conv_params.setattr('grad_req', 'null')
```

or simply

```py
>>> net.collect_params('(?!dense).*').setattr('grad_req', 'null')
```

Here we exclude all the parameters matching `dense` to get only `conv` blocks and set their `grad_req` attributes to `'null'`. Now, training the model `net` with `mxnet.gluon.Trainer` will update only `dense` parameters.

---

It is more convenient to have a pretrained model with separate attributes indicating specific blocks, e.g. the features block, anchor generators etc. In our case, we have a convolutional network that extracts features and passes them to an output block.

```py
class ConvNet(mx.gluon.nn.HybridSequential):
    def __init__(self, n_classes, params=None, prefix=None):
        super().__init__(params=params, prefix=prefix)

        self.features = mx.gluon.nn.HybridSequential()
        self.features.add(mx.gluon.nn.Conv2D(channels=6, kernel_size=5, padding=2,
                          activation='sigmoid'))
        self.add(mx.gluon.nn.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
        self.add(mx.gluon.nn.Flatten())

        self.output = mx.gluon.nn.Dense(units=n_classes)

    def hybrid_forward(self, F, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        return self.output(x)
```

With this convnet declaration, we don't have to use regexps to access required blocks:

```py
>>> net = ConvNet(n_classes=10)
>>> net.features.collect_params().setattr('grad_req', 'null')
```

Gluon CV models follow exactly this pattern. See the documentation of the desired model and choose the blocks you would like to freeze. If the docs are empty, run
`collect_params` to see all the parameters and filter out with regexp the ones to fine-tune and set the returned parameters' `grad_req` to `'null'`.